# How do I display the new Squeak background in my trunk image?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, morphic

I have a Squeak 4.3 image that I have updated through 4.4 by using the `trunk` update stream, which pulls down source code updates from the Monticello repository [here](http://source.squeak.org/trunk)

How do I get the new 4.4 desktop? In particular, how do I replace the brown antique paper background with the new grey Ulam Spiral background?

Comment: Later on, I plan to answer my own question with: Most of the desktop is easy to update. On the Extras menu in the world docking bar, there is a 'Rebuild Menus' command. After that, the new welcome workspaces can be found under the Help menu.

To update to the new background on your home project, evaluate this in a workspace:

> `World color: MorphicProject defaultFill`

Comment: It is too late to edit my comment, but the last sentence is wrong. The `defaultFill` form is the grey brushed metal wallpaper that was already in the image. It is used for new Morphic projects. Nice but not new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the wallpaper itself [here](https://github.com/frankshearar/squeak-ci/blob/master/resources/wallpaper.png). (This URL points to the wallpaper of the current Squeak release, but you ought to have at least 6 months from today before it changes :) )

Wallpaper in hand, and assuming that the image is in your current directory, you need just evaluate `Form openAsBackground: (FileDirectory default / 'wallpaper.png') pathName`.

(I should add that the background image is intentionally not part of the update stream: it would bloat images, and change people's existing backgrounds. Thus, it's applied (along with a few other tweaks) "on the side" [by the release process](https://github.com/frankshearar/squeak-ci/blob/master/release.st).)

Comment: Works perfectly (and instantly.) Those mysterious diagonal lines are quite evident in your image. Thanks, Frank, and thanks for the insight into the *release* portion of `squeak-ci`.