# Squeak (or pharo) change windows default white background color

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak, morphic

How can I change the default white window background color in Squeak or Pharo ? I am new to smalltalk and Morphic, i looked at the morphic classes but did not found the correct instance variables. Thanks.

Comment: See this previous post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123990/how-do-i-display-the-new-squeak-background-in-my-trunk-image

Comment: it is not the "world" background that i want to change, but the white background of windows, for example of the Transcript window

Answer (score 0):

I think this question may be closer to what you need.

Looks like you may have to use a tiled window manager.

[Colored Window Theme in Pharo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569611/colored-window-theme-in-pharo)

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this:

```
| morph |

SystemWindow new 
    addMorph: (morph := Morph new) fullFrame: LayoutFrame identity;
    openInWorld.

morph color: Color red.
```

*Note: this is on Pharo*

Answer (score 0):

On Pharo (I used 3.0), check the UITheme hierarchy.

For quick hacking, you can directly edit UITheme and subclasses. For a more permanent solution, create your own subclass and install it as the current theme. To change the background color of all Transcripts, as you requested, you would override #textEditorNormalFillStyleFor:, as you can see in the ugly (for effect) screenshot...

[image: Pharo default window color changed]